# data store in client with angular

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, web-sql, datastore

we have heavy forms view in an Angular application based on ERP, we need store data that we data entry in some forms. When the user refreshes the browser data must appeared in the forms and forms must be open.
what is the best way for this cases?
we research about WebSQL and IndexedDB and NgRx, but we don't know what is useful for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Storing your form data to indexedDB is a good fit for your usecase, alternatives are session storage and local storage.

Comment: thank you. Can you send some sample links for this implementation?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage or https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/keeping-browser-tabs-in-sync-using-localstorage-ngrx-and-rxjs

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to store large data set then indexedDB would be best fit.

If data is less and wants to should persist after browser reopen then localStorage would be best fit.

If data is less and don't want to persist after browser reopen then sessionStorage would be best fit.